# Problems loading jpg after deploy of an mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7

I have an MVC website that is deployed as an application.

[image]

The problem is when I try to load the content, there are files that don't load correctly. In my Layout page I have this code that points to the Images folder to load the logo.png. If I deploy the project as a website instead as a sub application of a website, then I don't get any error.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home/Index">
                        <h1><img class="img-responsive" src=@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png") alt="logo" /></h1>
                    </a>
```

Now as an sub application, when it loads the logo.png is trying to get it through this address:

```
http://dev-environment.com/Images/logo.png
```

that of course is not finding it(404 Not Found). Actually I want that the request generated should look like this

```
 <img class="img-responsive" alt="logo" src="/Home/Images/logo.png" />
```

Doing that I would load the png correctly, the thing is that I don't want to hardcode the path.

Here is the structure of the project

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: where in the application your images are located ?

Comment: @Shyju I updated the question