# Bundle is not working after deployment on IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, web-deployment

After I deploy my website, the browser doesn't load correctly all the css. Therefore if I go to my webconfig and put the debug mode to true instead of false, I get it work.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2">
```

What I am doing wrong?

This is my Bundle configuration, I put all the css to work with `CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper`, because the application was not loading correctly the images that were part of a the css([Problems loading jpg after deploy of an mvc application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814640/problems-loading-jpg-after-deploy-of-an-mvc-application)).
 Anyways I don't know if that could be the problem here. I deploy the application locally and it works, but when I am trying to put it on my staging environment it fails

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            #region JsBundles

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scriptsBundle").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/angular.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                //"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.inview.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/wow.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/mousescroll.js",
                "~/Scripts/smoothscroll.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.countTo.js",
                "~/Scripts/lightbox.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                "~/Scripts/main.js"
                )
            );

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/toogleJs").Include(
               "~/Scripts/bootstrap-toggle.js"
           ));

            #endregion

            #region CssBundle

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/Site.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper()));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssBundle")
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.default.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.default.mobile.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
                    new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css",
                    new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/animate.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/lightbox.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/main.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/responsive.css")
                .Include("~/Content/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
                .Include("~/Content/App/Receipt/receipt.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper())
            );

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/toogleCss")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap-toggle.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransformWrapper()
                ));

            #endregion
        }
```

Comment: use firebug or developer tools in your browser to see which css files can't be load in release mode

Comment: and check that your css files has cssfile.min.css
I guess for release mode use cssfile.min.css files